# Enter on one passport, leave on another

Tags: usa, uk

I hold both US and UK passports but will reside in the UK for the duration.  I just wanted to know if it is OK to enter the US on my US passport but leave only showing my UK passport when i return to the UK?  i.e. only show my US passport at Heathrow and only show my UK passport at JFK.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes to me that should be fine. Aslongs your flight ticket matches your passport number

Comment: Any particular reason to show only one passport when checking in?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan to avoid confusing the clerks and/or prolonging the check-in process.  If you show them two, do they scan both?

Comment: User67718: I do this all the time, never had a problem, though my non-US citizenship is of another EU country, which I suppose doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @phoog I don't know specifically about two passports, but I travel with a US green card and a British Citizen passport. When traveling between the UK and US I always show both on check-in, and it does not seem to cause any problems. Before the US I-94 went electronic, it was necessary to show my green card on leaving the US to stop the check-in agent searching through my passport for an I-94.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan odd.  I've checked in dozens of times to leave the US with a Dutch passport and nobody ever asked about an I- 94 (and my wife has several that airline agents neglected to remove).  It seems you've been encountering more conscientious agents than have we. But I'll add that online check-in facilities have commonly been able to accept both a passport and a residence permit for some years now; I've only once seen a system that accepted multiple passports, and that was last month.